# PHP Warning Illegal string offset in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a warning:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'alt' in /home/procsi/galina3000.ru/wp-content/themes/memoir/epanel/custom_functions.php on line 112
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in /home/procsi/galina3000.ru/wp-content/themes/memoir/epanel/custom_functions.php on line 113

The code is shown below:

```
if ( function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') ) {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
            $thumb_array['use_timthumb'] = false;
            
            $args='';
            if ($class <> '') $args['class'] = $class;
            if ($alttext <> '') $args['alt'] = $alttext;
            if ($titletext <> '') $args['title'] = $titletext;
            
            $thumb_array['thumb'] = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array($width,$height), $args );
            
            if ($fullpath) {
                $thumb_array['fullpath'] = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
                if ($thumb_array['fullpath'] <> '') { 
                    $thumb_array['fullpath'] = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $thumb_array['fullpath'], $matches);
                    $thumb_array['fullpath'] = trim($matches[1][0]);
                }
            }
        }
```

How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you write the title in English as well, please?

Comment: `$args` is a string. You've defined it as a string with `$args='';`, but you're accessing it as an array with `$args['title']` etc.

Comment: @Variable, please don't translate posts for people. They need to be able to do it themselves. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content#297680

Comment: @Don'tPanic The other half was already in english, but I didn't know that I must not translate questions, will read that, thanks (ツ)

Comment: @Variable yeah, it's not a big deal in this case, just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to tell you that you're using a string as an array with a string as a key:

```
$args='';

if ($class <> '') $args['class'] = $class;
if ($alttext <> '') $args['alt'] = $alttext;
if ($titletext <> '') $args['title'] = $titletext;
```

Since you first declare `$args` to be a string (`''`), that's the type of the variable when you try to assign the other arguments to it.

If you instead declare it as an array - since you want to use it as an array, it should work as you expect:

```
$args = []; // or $args = array(); if PHP version < 5.4

if ($class <> '') $args['class'] = $class;
if ($alttext <> '') $args['alt'] = $alttext;
if ($titletext <> '') $args['title'] = $titletext;
```